# How was the relationship between the models?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have 3 models. SysPage and SysTab are static tables and i have their data. I want to pick some SysPage and some SysTab (not all tab of related SysPage) for module.
So I made a relationship between SysModule and SysTab by SysModulePage.

```
  public class SysModule 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<SysModulePage> Pages { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual List<SysPage> PageList => this.Pages?.Select(p => p.SysPage).ToList();

}

public class SysModulePage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? SysPageId { get; set; }
    public SysPage SysPage { get; set; }

    public int? ModuleId { get; set; }
    public SysModule Module { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<SysModulePageTab> ModuleTabs { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual List<SysTab> ModuleTabList => this.ModuleTabs?.Select(p => p.SysTab).ToList();
}

public class SysModulePageTab 
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? SysModulePageId { get; set; }
    public SysModulePage SysModulePage { get; set; }
    public int? SysTabId { get; set; }
    public SysTab SysTab { get; set; }
}

    public class SysPage 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SysTab> SysTabList { get; set; }
}
public class SysTab 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? SysPageId { get; set; }
    public SysPage SysPage { get; set; }
}
```

I get SysModule data with EF in .Net Core Api.

```
var res = _rootContext.SysModules
        .Include(p => p.Pages).ThenInclude(p => p.SysPage)
        .Include(p => p.Pages).ThenInclude(p => p.ModuleTabs).ThenInclude(p => p.SysTab);
```

I have SysTabList sub PageList at this result. But SysTab isn't included from SysPage. How did that happen?

[example of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucwn0.png)

Comment: Is the question why you are seeing Navigation Properties populated that aren't in your Include's?  If so then it's probably that those Entities were loaded by one of your includes or a previous query on the DbContext, and you have Change Tracking enabled. "EF Core will also fix up navigation properties between the entities in a tracking query result and the entities that are in the change tracker."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking